# Protractor parallel testing at suite level

Tags: protractor

I know shredding(shardTestFiles: true, maxInstances: 2) can be used to run specs in parallel with in a suite. 
Is there a way to run in parallel at suite level?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, but you can look into running multiple `protractor` commands at the same time with different `--suite` values and parallelize on the higher level.